# Find $x_0$ when a 3x3 symmetric matrix has equal eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices

The question goes like this: There is a symmetric matrix:$$A=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & x & 2\\0 & 2 & x\end{bmatrix}$$

Find the value(s) of $x$ for which $A$ has at most two distinct eigenvalues. (Eigenvalues like $3,2,2$)

In my attempts to solve this problem, I got the characteristic equation as:
$$\lambda^3-(2x+3)\lambda^2+(x^2+3x-2)\lambda-3(x^2-4)=0$$
I am unable to proceed any further than this. Should I try to solve for $\lambda$ by putting appropriate values in the equation, then find $x$?

Is there any property that I seem to be missing?

Comment: You can decompose the matrix into one 1x1 block (containing $3$) and a 2x2 block. So one eigenvalue is always $3$. The char. polynomial is $(z-3)((z-x)^2-4)$.

Comment: I found a similar question,https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1916681/592530 to mine, but I did not understand the explanation

Comment: I tried out what @amsmath has mentioned, but what do I do afterwards? Please elaborate

Comment: So, you can't figure out the two other eigenvalues?

Comment: @amsmath I'm getting $\lambda=\mp 2 + x$ . But the question mentions atleast 2 values of $\lambda$ to be equal. In the case of all the eigenvalues being equal I get $x=5,1$ So how to I find out the remaining values of x?

Comment: It's certainly overkill in this case, but for more complicated matrices the following approach can be reasonable: The problem is equivalently asking for the $x$ for which the characteristic polynomial $c_A$ of $A$ has a multiple root, but a polynomial has a multiple root iff its discriminant is $0$. For $c_A$, computing and factoring the discriminant gives $16 (x - 1)^2 (x - 5)^2$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant

Comment: $x=5$ is correct since $-2+5 = 3$. But as also $+2+1 = 3$ the other $x$ is $x=1$. Remark: for $x=5$ the eigenvalues are NOT all equal because two are 3 and one is 5+2 = 7.

Comment: @travis , I'm not able to understand your explanation. (I've just started freshman year and I don't know a LOT.) Please bare with me

Comment: @evamPUNdit No problem---my remark intended mostly as color commentary previewing something you might well see later, or perhaps even want to read up on in the meantime if it sounds interesting. Most undergraduates probably don't learn about it, but the notion of discriminant is certainly accessible to a freshman. You've already seen the quantity $b^2-4ac$ show up in the quadratic formula and the completing-the-square formula---this is exactly the discriminant for quadratic polynomials. For this problem using the factorization that amsmath suggests is surely the fastest way to start.

Comment: The notion I'm talking about is the *discriminant*, not the determinant. The discriminant is a number that can be assigned to any polynomial---just like we assign $b^2 - 4 a c$ to any quadratic $a t^2 + b t + c$---and it has the property that it is zero if and only if the polynomial has a repeated root.

Comment: In particular, applying this method means that you don't have to factor $c_A$, and it tells you the parameter values $x$ for which there is a repeated eigenvalue without actually having to compute those eigenvalues in the first place, just as checking whether $b^2 - 4 a c = 0$ tells us whether or not a quadratic has a repeated root without requiring us to compute the roots outright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that 
$$A\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}=3\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$
Thus $\lambda=3$ is an eigenvalue of this matrix.

Also observe
$$A\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}=(x+2)\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$
Thus $\lambda=x+2$ is an eigenvalue of this matrix as well.

Now the sum of the eigenvalues is the trace of the matrix. Let the other eigenvalue be $\lambda_3$, then
$$3+(x+2)+\lambda_3=2x+3 \implies \color{red}{\lambda_3=x-2}.$$

So the three eigenvalues are $\boxed{3,x+2}$ and $\boxed{x-2}$. We want at most two distinct eigenvalues. Observe that when $x=1,5$ then two of them are equal, hence only two distinct eigenvalues.

When $\color{red}{x=1}$, the eigenvalues are $\color{blue}{3,3,-1}$.

When $\color{red}{x=5}$, the eigenvalues are $\color{blue}{3,7,3}$.

When $\color{red}{x \neq 1,5}$, the eigenvalues are all $\color{blue}{\text{distinct}}$.

For no value of $x$ can all the eigenvalues be the same.

---

**Further addition to the solution:**

In case you are not aware of the trace result, you can still get the third eigenvalue by observing that
$$A\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix}=(x-2)\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix}.$$
Thus $\lambda=x-2$ is an eigenvalue of this matrix as well.

Answer (score 0):

you should not have solved all you parentheses
you  had $$(3-\lambda)*[(x-\lambda)^2-4)]$$
so $$(3-\lambda)=0$$ is one solution  and $$[(x-\lambda)^2-4)]=0$$ the next.